# Dealing with a BaseException in Python Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am trying to integrate Sentry for reporting errors in my Flask app, but I had a problem recently when a third-party library caused a `BaseException` to be thrown inside one of my handlers. I see that Flask has no problem dealing with `Exception`, yet `BaseException` basically causes the app to stop working. A simple example:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    raise BaseException('Bummer! Exception')
    return 'Hello world'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5004)
```

Calling the route I get:

```
$ curl localhost:5004
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

subsequent calls to the app leave curl hanging, waiting for a response.

I have tried using the `errorhandler` decorator like so:

```
@app.errorhandler(BaseException)
def handle():
    print("Whoops.")
```

but Flask gives me an error:

```
    assert issubclass(exc_class, Exception)
AssertionError
```

Which is fair enough. I understand that this third-party library should have been sub-classing `Exception`, not `BaseException`, but still I am hoping there is a way to deal with such errors in Flask and end the request.

Comment: if you know the handler which triggers the exception, why not using `try/except BaseException as e:` to catch it?

Comment: I only know the handler in this particular example. It could occur anywhere throughout the app, especially as in this case where a third-party package raised the `BaseException`